# Why there's Zero Or One to Many relation between these two models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relationship

I'm building a model for ASP.NET MVC6,
The design I'm working on is simple: **One course may have one or more instructors.**
Here are my models:

```
public class Instructor
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
}
public class Course
   {
       [Required]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Title { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Description { get; set; }
   }
```

And this is the class that defines the relation between course and instructors:

```
 public class Course_Instructor_Relationship
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int InstructorId{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    }
```

As I can see in the model diagram, there's `zero or one to many` relation between `Course_Instructor_Relationship` and `Instructor` whereas I was expecting a `one to many` relation.
I can not figure out why.

Comment: Normally such relationship is expressed by FK in `Instructor`, not sure why you need that link entity (table). And of course it cannot contain `ICollection<Instructor>` - the collection property must be in the `Course` class and to be of type `ICollection<Course_Instructor_Relationship>`.

Comment: Why are you adding InstructorId to the Course_Instructor_Relationship entity?

Comment: @yosoy Well, Actually I have no idea what I'm doing. Just bashing on keyboard really. Do you know any good resource to learn more about this topic?

Comment: Yes, sure, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *zero or one to many* relation because you are not making the Course entity Required, so it can be null and that's why EF generate the relation as zero or one to many.

I think that from the name of your entities one Course can have one or many Instructors and one Instructor can be on zero to many courses. If this is right you can do as follow:

```
public class Instructor
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public List<Course> Courses{get;set;}
}

public class Course
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Instructor> Instructors{get;set;}
}
```

If not: you can do:

```
public class Instructor
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    public Course Course{get;set;}
}

public class Course
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors{get;set;}
}
```

You can also specify the mappings to specify exactly the relation that you want:

```
public class InstructorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Instructor>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Instructor> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

        builder.HasMany(i => i.Courses);

        builder.ToTable("Instructors");
    }
}


public class CourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
{
    public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

        builder.HasMany(i => i.Instructors);

        builder.ToTable("Courses");
    }
}
```

Or as you want:

```
    public class InstructorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Instructor>
    {
        public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Instructor> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Course);

            builder.ToTable("Instructors");
        }
    }


    public class CourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
    {
        public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Course> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

            builder.HasMany(i => i.Instructors);

            builder.ToTable("Courses");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for explaining this much details. I learned a lot from your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I change  List<Course> to ICollection<Course> and respectively do this for Instructor too, No relation between Course and Instructor table forms. Could you explain why is that, please?

Comment: When you declare List<T> you are forcing EF to create and populate a concrete class. With ICollection<T> EF can use any data structure that implements ICollection<T>. Can you debug you code and check witch type it is? Maybe that give you a clue of why.

Comment: Also, it is not always necessary to have a third table to handle the relation, it depends of the kind of relation itself.

Comment: You can always check the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) to understand better the relations in EF.